# Preventing Concurrent Activity Creation

Tags: joomla, activities

I want to use CiviCRM in a new project right now. In this project, it is necessary to assume an activity. So before creating an event for xxx individual registration, this xxx individual transaction must undertake. No one else who has taken over the registration and who has the authority to open a record in Joomla / CiviCRM on this individual until the transaction (new activity) completes.

Here's the story. Only joomla users can access CRM. When a person is interviewed, a Phone Call activity is created for this. If there is a need for additional support, the shared e-mail address of the related team is added to the Assigned section. Since there is more than one person from the common e-mail address, more than one person can make transactions at the same time. I want to prevent anyone else from taking action on this record by doing something like (assume) after viewing the CiviCRM Record in this mail.

If this is possible, I would like to know how to do this, or if there is an add-on created before.

Answer (score 1):

By "complete", I'm assuming you are talking about the status of the activity?

You will need to develop an extension to implement your specific workflow, as there isn't anything in civi preventing having multiple activities with various status and your workflow seems to be specific enough that it's unlikely someone else has done and shared something similar.

The safest point is probably as a pre hook, ie before saving an activity, check that the required other activities with the expected status are there.

However, it this would be a sub-optimal user experience, as a user might start creating the activity without realising it will not be possible to save (because of the pre-hook).

So you should probably alter the display of the contact (as it seems to be the main path to create a new activity) and add a message/change color/add a warning message "this contact is reserved because activity bla has the status..."

Please do share if you implement it, it might help others, at least as inspiration and starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @xavier We agree partially. I have used this process on a CRM system called Mi4Biz. I don't have any coding information to do what you say. My knowledge of English is not enough to explain this situation more clearly. I write here with Google Translete. He often makes different meanings. So I'm using the example in almost every questions statement.

Let me give you another example.
Welcome Team, Sales Team and Confirmation Team as 3 gutup Think.

The Welcome Team opens a recording when a call is made. If a payment is to be received from the interviewee, it directs it to the Sales Team. It records the activity in the Assigned field by typing the group into the E-mail address.

Now he went to this activity as an e-mail to everyone in the mail group. One of them should be quick to call back and get paid. However, everyone has the possibility to call the person at the same time. There is also the possibility that everyone can create an activity at the same time. Therefore, the first person who enters the activity record or wants to do the operation first must lock the record so that no one else can create the activity. After the person in this Team makes the sales search, the Confirmation Team records the group e-mail address in the Assigned section.

Thanks to the e-mail to the team to check the registration of one of them to confirm the process and if any product is out. In this way, no one's job is interfering with the other and the process is prevented at the same time.

I hope GoogleTranslate has translated properly. :)

Comment: If you use Cases - from memory - you can limit the number of times a specific Activity Type can occur in the Case. If you limit it to one then you may have what you want.

Comment: "Allow Multiple Case Clients". However, I was not using the CiviCase component. I had previously disabled this component because it was active because I had problems installing it. Now when I set the value to "Let each event be a customer", will not more than one person create the same ID for the activity at the same time?

Comment: By the way, I tried. That's not what I want. It doesn't work for the process I want.